# Boolean Outputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

This is a rookie question, I know - but I'm struggling to find an answer elsewhere.  I've written a little app that has several checkbox fields.  All I need to do is have an "X" appear by Yes or No in my form.  I'm attempting to use the 'if' function and have written this:

`<%= if @pc.part_a '1' then 'X' %><% end %>`

But it's not working. I know this is foolishly simple, but I'm hoping someone can show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What's your expected output, and what's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%- if @pc.part_a == '1' %>
  'X'
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect.  I knew it was an easy one, just couldn't get my head around it.  Thanks!

Comment: Rails idiom would prefer you did this for boolean fields: `<℅ if @pc.part_a? ℅>`